# Find the value of a and b if $( x + 1 )$ and $( x -2 )$ are factors of $ ax^3 - 4x^2 + bx - 12$

Tags: polynomials

Find the value of $a$ and $b$ if $( x + 1 )$ and $( x -2 )$ are factors of $ax^3 - 4x^2 + bx - 12$. This is regarding polynomials.

Thank you